# Tonsuring story of Neela Devi giving her hair to Lord Vishnu

Tags: vishnu

How long have Indian people known about the legend of Neela Devi giving her hair to Lord Vishnu after he was hit on the head and lost some hair? is this a well known story in India? Has it been around for a while? Does anyone know which Hindu scripture it can be found in?

Comment: It's from a sthala purana in South India, definitely the tirupati temple, it's not a well known story throughout India every temple have such backstory myths- which are generally not found in scriptures.

Comment: The question is not an exact duplicate of " Why does one get their head tonsured and offer the hair to Lord Venkateswara in Tirupati?" but while answering there maybe some overlapping with this question. Should be left open.

Comment: Thank you. Do you know which sthala purana has the story about neela Devi? I would really like to find the scriptual source for this story. It does seem to be all over the internet now as the reason for tonsuring at Tirumala- its on many websites and blogs and in many articles and even books